# How to add whole project to staging with git?

Tags: git

I have a problem,  was working on the project alone. I have enabled git hooks on the production server.

The client decided to hire a freelancer since I was busy with another project.

The problem is that the freelancer uploaded MANUALLY to the production server oldest version of the application and overweight some of the functions that were done before. So how can I synchronize versions in production? Because whenever I make a push to production it uploads new changes but does not upload old ones because thinks that there are present.

Any ideas what would be the best solution to fix it?

Comment: If you know what version the freelancer started from, create a branch from there. Then commit the work on top of it. You could now merge master and the new branch and be in sync again

Comment: @Simson But the problem is I'm not sure what version he started on,  and how exactly I can tell that this code is not present in the production. Is there a way to add the whole project to staging and the add it in one commit?

Comment: Even if you only know approximately where he started from gitk and git difftool --dir-diff will enable you to see where things start to disappear.

Comment: Are you able to download from the production server to your dev workspace or is this also part of the problem?

Comment: @Simson even if I checkout and make new branch out on the approximate commit, and then merge it. It will still think that everything is updated on production. Because I pushed changes to production before guy upload the zip file with older version with his work into the production instead of git push. But he made a git push to origin so, on origin I have all the work together sync.